# injection of property in xml fails (spring-ws config)

Tags: spring, spring-ws

i'm using Spring-WS and have the following spring-ws-servlet.xml file.
The injection of defaultURI and marshaller doesn't work because when i get to the method in the client of the service these properties are null.
What happens is that the setters are being called with correct values, but in the method of the client getSum() these values are null. What could be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
   xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.coral.project.endpoints"/>

<sws:annotation-driven />

<sws:dynamic-wsdl id="test" portTypeName="TestCase" locationUri="/testService/"
                  targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/schemasDef/test/definitions">
    <sws:xsd location="/WEB-INF/schemasDef/test.xsd"/>
</sws:dynamic-wsdl>

<bean id="springWSClient" class="com.coral.project.endpoints.SpringWSClient">
    <property name="defaultUri" value="http://localhost:8080/parking/springServices/testService"/>
    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.coral.project.entity.Street"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
</beans>
```

i get the exception:

Exception while calling encodeEnd on component : {Component-Path : [Class: org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot,ViewId: /appealConversionStatusReport.jsp][Class: org.apache.myfaces.custom.div.Div,Id: j_id_jsp_1406177460_4][Class: com.exadel.htmLib.components.UITable,Id: j_id_jsp_1406177460_5][Class: com.exadel.htmLib.components.UITbody,Id: j_id_jsp_1406177460_6][Class: org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlInputHidden,Id: j_id_jsp_546672833_0]}

Caused by:
java.lang.IllegalStateException - No marshaller registered. Check configuration of WebServiceTemplate.

the client:

```
package com.coral.project.endpoints;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;
import org.springframework.xml.transform.StringSource;

import com.coral.project.dao.ifc.StreetDao;
import com.coral.project.entity.Street;
import com.coral.utils.SpringUtils;

public class SpringWSClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

public void getSum() throws SOAPException, IOException, TransformerException {
    StreetDao streetDao = SpringUtils.getBean(StreetDao.class);
    Street street = streetDao.findById(1);

    getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(
    "http://localhost:8080/parking/springServices/testService",street);

}
}
```

Comment: Stupid mistake!!! Was making new SpringWSClient() instead of injecting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you `new`'ing the `SpringWSClient` instance in your code?

Also, for the streetDao, you shouldn't need to use `SpringUtils.getBean`. Instead, it should be a field annotated with `@Autowired` (or `@Resource`).