# Need to match my soap request with what SoapUI is sending

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb, wsdl

I am sending a request to a webservice but it seems the request is invalid. I am sending a similar request using SoapUI and the webservice accepts it. I need to change my request to what SoapUI sends. How can I add namespaces to my request?  **WSDL** is [here](http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx?wsdl).

I visited following pages but could not find a solution yet. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865057/jibx-classes-generated-from-maven-codegen-plugin-no-unmarshaller-for-element),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189601/injection-of-property-in-xml-fails-spring-ws-config),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597543/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-scope-registered-for-scope-session)

**Code**

SearchFlights

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SearchFlights")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchFlights {
    @XmlElement(name = "SoapMessage")
    private SoapMessage soapMessage;

    getter and setter
```

SoapMessage

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SoapMessage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WegoloSoapMessage {
    @XmlElement(name = "Username")
    private String username;
    @XmlElement(name = "Password")
    private String password;
    @XmlElement(name = "LanguageCode")
    private String languageCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "Request")
    private Request request;

    getters and setters
```

Request

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Request {
    @XmlElement(name = "Departure")
    private String departure;
    @XmlElement(name = "Destination")
    private String destination;
    @XmlElement(name = "DepartureDate")
    private String departureDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "ReturnDate")
    private String returnDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "NumADT")
    private int numADT;
    @XmlElement(name = "NumINF")
    private int numInf;
    @XmlElement(name = "NumCHD")
    private int numCHD;
    @XmlElement(name = "CurrencyCode")
    private String currencyCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "WaitForResult")
    private boolean waitForResult;
    @XmlElement(name = "NearByDepartures")
    private boolean nearByDepartures;
    @XmlElement(name = "NearByDestinations")
    private boolean nearByDestinations;
    @XmlElement(name = "RROnly")
    private boolean rronly;
    @XmlElement(name = "MetaSearch")
    private boolean metaSearch;

getters and setters
```

jaxb.index

```
SearchFlights
Flight
Flights
Leg
Legs
Outbound
Request
Response
WegoloSoapMessage
```

**Code to send request**

```
    try {
        SaajSoapMessageFactory soapMsgFac = new SaajSoapMessageFactory(
                MessageFactory.newInstance());
        soapMsgFac.afterPropertiesSet();

        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(
                soapMsgFac);
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();

        marshaller.setContextPath("com.myprojet.flights.wegolo");
        marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

        Response response = (Response) webServiceTemplate
                .marshalSendAndReceive(
                        "http://www5v80.elsyarres.net/service.asmx",
                        searchFlights,
                        new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
                            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage message) 
                            {
                                ((SoapMessage)message).setSoapAction("ElsyArres.API/SearchFlights");
                            }
                       }
                   );

        Response msg = (Response) response;
        System.err.println("Wegolo >>>"
                + msg.getFlights().getFlight().size());
    } catch (Exception s) {
        s.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**My Request**

[image]
[image]

**SoapUI request**

[image]
[image]

Comment: so your issue is that your code isn't adding the els namespace? or is there something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your request there is no namesapce before elements like in request from SoapUI.

For example your element:

```
<SearchFlights>
```

SoupUI element:

```
<els:SearchFlights>
```

You should add namespace `xmlns:els="ElsyArres.API"` and prefix before all elements using code form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895486/jaxb-need-namespace-prefix-to-all-the-elements) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979762/adding-namespaces-to-root-element-of-xml-using-jaxb) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294065/jaxb-namespace-prefixes-missing).